# How to resolve attribute error in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, object, text-to-speech

on the begin I'll say that I was looking for the answer but can't find it and sorry for so basic question.I created program with TTS. I created global variable called "list_merge", but most of you said that global variables are BAD. So I decided to put this list in init. PS. ignore whitespaces, they exist only because I copied it here.

the error is: 
AttributeError: 'Ver2ProjectWithTTS' object has no attribute 'list_merge'

```
import json
import pyttsx
from openpyxl import load_workbook

class Ver2ProjectWithTTS(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.read_json_file()
        self.read_xml_file()
        self.say_something()
        self.list_merge = []

    def read_json_file(self):
        with open("json-example.json", 'r') as df:
            json_data = json.load(df)
            df.close()
        for k in json_data['sentences']:
            text_json = k['text']
            speed_json = int(k['speed'])
            volume_json = float(k['volume'])
            dict_json = {'text': text_json, 'speed': speed_json, 'volume': volume_json}
            self.list_merge.append(dict_json)

    def read_xml_file(self):
        tree = et.parse('xml-example.xml')
        root = tree.getroot()
        for k in range(0, len(root)):
            text_xml = root[k][0].text
            speed_xml = int(root[k][1].text)
            volume_xml = float(root[k][2].text)
            dict_xml = {'text': text_xml, 'speed': speed_xml, 'volume': volume_xml}
            self.list_merge.append(dict_xml)

    def say_something(self):
        for item in self.list_merge:
            engine = pyttsx.init()
            engine.getProperty('rate')
            engine.getProperty('volume')
            engine.setProperty('rate', item['speed'])
            engine.setProperty('volume', item['volume'])
            engine.say(cleared_text)
            engine.runAndWait()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    a = Ver2ProjectWithTTS()
```

I'm getting
AttributeError: 'Ver2ProjectWithTTS' object has no attribute 'list_merge'

Any ideas how to avoid this error? Well i'm not good in objectivity and I just cant move on without fixing this. PS. with global variable before init def it worked properly.
Thanks for help :)

Comment: what line is throwing this error?

Comment: AttributeError: 'Ver2ProjectWithTTS' object has no attribute 'list_merge'

Comment: It's hard to 'ignore whitespaces' when they are part of the syntax. Is that your actual indentation ?

Comment: You *still* didn't say which line is throwing this error.

Comment: I mean, there are no tabs in this code which I printed for you, but in mine it's all ok. :) I know whitespaces are important and the problem isnt with whitespaces. :)

Comment: @DanielRoseman, it print in  line 27, in read_json_file
    self.list_merge.append(dict_json)
 and it will put error any time I use self.list_merge it seems.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to set if first before you use it:

```
class Ver2ProjectWithTTS(object):

    def __init__(self):
        # first set it
        self.list_merge = []
        self.read_json_file()
        self.read_xml_file()
        self.say_something()
```

Anyway don't do any advanced logic in constructors, it's not a good practice. Make a method instead:

```
class Ver2ProjectWithTTS(object):

    def __init__(self):
        # first set it
        self.list_merge = []

    def do_the_job(self):
        self.read_json_file()
        self.read_xml_file()
        self.say_something()

    ...

instance = Ver2ProjectWithTTS()
instance.do_the_job()
```

Comment: Thanks, great answer. :-)